# Is NUMA Enabled?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, numa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HP DL360p with Intel E5-2630 NUMA Capable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/404487/hp-dl360p-with-intel-e5-2630-numa-capable)

i have an brand new HP DL380p Gen 8 with Windows server 2008R2 Enterprise Edition and i want to check if numa is enabled and how can disable.
how can check this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DL380p is NUMA-capable. It's the system default.

Comment: thanks how can disable numa? because i want to run oracle 11g application and i think that numa is a performance penalty.

Comment: Look in the BIOS options.